# React.js State is not defined in class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a class component without a constructor to initialize state. Today, every react app i have tried to create has given me an error

```
  Line 4:3:  'state' is not defined  no-undef
```

my code is

```
class Page extends Component {
  state = {
    pages: []
}

  render() {
    return(
      <div>page</div>
    );
  }
}

export default Page;
```

the weird part is in my old react apps it works fine. but every new 'npx create-react-app <>' i have tried today all give me undefined unless i use a class constructor.

here are my dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
```

Comment: I will clarify again that using a constructor will work fine, but I am trying to figure out why I need to do that in the first place. just state = {} should work, and it does in my recent react projects, but is not working in fresh react projects

Comment: I have tried on my machine with your code and it still works

Comment: @HenryLe is that with a fresh react project using npx create-react-app? My code works fine in older projects, but starting up a new one using npx and using that code fails to compile every time for me

Comment: the code looks ok, it seems some issue with the setup. Try to delete the node_module folder and run `npm install` again. It would be good if you can add full package.json file as well.

Comment: I have the same issue, when I clone my old CRA app from Git and install packages, it does not build with state={}, it also does not like the lambda functions. Looks like some React update is messy.

Comment: Seems there is an issue with React version `16.3.1` I was having this issue today and came to this thread. Finally, after upgrading my npm react version from `16.3.1` to `16.4.0`, my code is free of this issue.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10598 looks like there was an issue as a lot of other reports. tested again this morning with a new npx create-react-app and it works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is an issue with React version 16.3.1
I was having this issue today and came to this thread. Finally, after upgrading my npm react version from 16.3.1 to 16.4.0, my code is free of this issue.

Comment: In my case I had to update react-scripts to 4.0.1 in package.json

Answer (score 0):

Class component should be like this. Reference link of documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

```
class Page extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          pages: []
      }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>page</div>
    );
  }
}

export default Page;
```

Comment: That is the traditional approach but the syntax `state = ` should work as well in newer versions of React.  This user is having some sort of issue with their environment.

Comment: Absolutely you can use newer syntax but you need to upgrade your packages version

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'

class Page extends React.Component{
  state = {
    pages: []
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>page</div>
    );
  }
}

export default Page;
```